# Android: how can I change the color of a textview when a button is pressed with selector XML

Tags: android, android-studio, android-xml, android-framelayout, android-selector

I have an imageButton. I created selector XML to change its background when it's pressed ... like this:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/default_blue" />
</selector>
```

and I used this in java with :

```
tempIBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttons_drawable_resource);
```

I have a textview and a pic on the image button (in addition to image of this imageButton.)

I want to change the color of this textview and pic when the imageButton is pressed but in selector tag I just can change attributes of imageButton not other textviews and... How can I do that?

Comment: a pic on the image button (in addition to image of this imageButton.) this line is bit confusing. for changing textview color you will require to create another xml and set it as background to textview when tempIBtn is pressed.

Comment: thanks :) my imagebutton and a linear layout are in a framelayout ... the LinearLayout contain a textview and a pic ... and how can I do this? I created another resource xml to change the drawable to white ... but how can I use it in java? how can I say when button is clicked change the color of the text view?

Comment: on button click obviously. inside button click you can but code to change color of textview

Comment: I don't want to change the color of textview completely I just want to change it when the button is pressed...

Comment: check touch listener it has actiondown and up. u can use that for your button and inside actiondown and up you can change textview color

Comment: Thanks :) I add this code :       `tempIBtn.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                avgTempTv.setTextColor(R.color.white);

                return true;
            }` but my OnClickListener is disabled ... isn't any way to do that with selectors?

Comment: Thanks again... It works :) `if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP || event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP)
                {
                    avgTempTv.setTextColor(R.color.default_blue);
                }else if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN || event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN)
                {
                    avgTempTv.setTextColor(R.color.white);
                }
                return false;` but I have another problem ... java don't know my colors !! Plz add ur answer to mark it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned you wish to change the color of textview but never mentioned color of text in textview. this can be done very easily using the same selector file. Implement this way for proper implementation, so you can just get things done inside onclicklistener no need to handle button states. Modify your selector file as

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/default_blue" android:color="@color/default_blue"/>
<item android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@color/default_color" android:color="@color/default_color"/>
</selector>
```

in your layout xml for textview set

```
android:textColor = "@drawable/buttons_drawable_resource"
```

**Note: Do not skip to add android:state_pressed="false" in selector as i gave above with default selections for button as well as textview text color else it will crash with NPE.**

Comment: thank u very much ... it solved by onTouchListener ... I want to change color of text in textView :)